# Wordpress validation error element dl is missing a required instance of child element dd

Tags: wordpress, gallery, shortcode

```
<dl class='gallery-item'>
<dt class='gallery-icon'>
                <a href='http://xxx.lt/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/snow-004.jpg' title='snow 004'><img width="200" height="81" src="http://xxx.lt/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/snow-004-200x81.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="snow 004" /></a>
            </dt>
</dl>
```

In wordpress I insert shartcode `[gallery link="file" columns="3"]` , when validating site with W3C, get error `Element dl is missing a required instance of child element dd`. It's a wordpress bug ? HOW to solve this error ? Maybe add  tag in `gallery_shortcode()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is Wordpress uses the dd for the image caption, see the code in media.php.
Add a caption to each image in the gallery then remove the caption via a "display none" in the css.

```
<div class="my_class">    
 <div class='gallery'>
  <dl class='gallery-item'>
   <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'> 
    <img width="190" height="190" src="XXXX" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="X" />
   </dt>
   <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>Some Caption</dd>
  </dl>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my_class .wp-caption-text.gallery-caption{
 display: none;
}
```

Just in case anyone else is looking for this.
Bit of a mess about, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same issue just now and when searching google this is the first page that shows up.

The html validator was giving me errors about the gallery and I was able to fix it by adding the following code to functions.php --

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-list', 'comment-form', 'search-form', 'gallery', 'caption', 'style', 'script' ) );
```